# position:sticky div not sticky at the bottom of the screen

Tags: html, css

I have a div like this :

**HTML**

```
<div class="row" style="min-height: calc(100vh - 81px);">
    <aside class="col-lg-3" style="padding-top: 8px; background: rgb(227, 227, 227); padding-left: 20px;">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <div id="treeparent"></div>
    </aside>
    <div class="col-lg-7 pt-2"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2" style="border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0.25rem; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(234, 35, 40); border-image: linear-gradient(rgb(179, 108, 219), rgb(235, 73, 113)) 0 0 0 100% / 1 / 0 stretch;">
        <div id="tocOut">
            <div>
                <h1 id="this-is-a-title" class="header-toc">
                    <a href="#this-is-a-title" title="This is a title">
                        <span>This is a title</span>
                    </a>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#tocOut {
    position: sticky;
    padding-top: 8px;
    top: 81px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The problem is that the `#tocOut` div does not stick of the top of the screen, I don't know why.

Comment: so do you want to stick at bottom or top, explain in brief

Answer (score 0):

Element is fixed only when the parent element is in the viewport and is higher than viewport, of course.

A little bit updated your code.

```css
#tocOut {
    position: -webkit-sticky; /*  */
    position: sticky;
    padding-top: 8px;
    top: 21px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="min-height: calc(100vh - 81px);">
    <aside class="col-lg-3" style="padding-top: 8px; background: rgb(227, 227, 227); padding-left: 20px;">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <div id="treeparent"></div>
    </aside>
    <div class="col-lg-7 pt-2"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2" style="border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0.25rem; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(234, 35, 40); border-image: linear-gradient(rgb(179, 108, 219), rgb(235, 73, 113)) 0 0 0 100% / 1 / 0 stretch;">
        <div id="tocOut">
            <div>
                <h1 id="this-is-a-title" class="header-toc">
                    <a href="#this-is-a-title" title="This is a title">
                        <span>This is a title</span>
                    </a>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>ANOTHER CONTENT<br>    <br>ANOTHER CONTENT<br>    <br>ANOTHER CONTENT<br>    <br>ANOTHER CONTENT<br>    <br>ANOTHER CONTENT<br>    <br>ANOTHER CONTENT<br>    <br>ANOTHER CONTENT<br>    <br>ANOTHER CONTENT<br>    <br>ANOTHER CONTENT<br>    <br>ANOTHER CONTENT<br>    <br>ANOTHER CONTENT<br>    <br>ANOTHER CONTENT<br>
    </div>
</div>
```